# How to enforce MFA only where the home directory requires it

Tags: azure-ad-b2b

I have an app that uses Azure AD B2B. Some guest directories require MFA logins, others do not. When signing in to my application, this is not enforced/required. Users that belong to an organisation that normally requires MFA are not prompted.

Azure B2B has the option to require MFA, but this would set it for all guest organizations. Is there an option to force Azure B2B to respect the requirements of the guests home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure B2B has the option to require MFA, but this would set it for all guest organizations. Is there an option to force Azure B2B to respect the requirements of the guest's home directory?

To assign the **MFA** to only selected **B2B users** in **Azure AD B2B**, you can follow the below steps.

To automatically move **B2B** users to a group instead of doing it manually, you can use a dynamic group. This group will move users to a particular group based on matching certain values.

1. I have created a Dynamic group for moving B2B users to group automatically as below.

**Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Groups > New Group**

[image]

2. External User creation
   [image]
3. Create a **conditional access policy** and assign it to the group as below.

**Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access > New policy.**

[image]
[image]

When I try to access the application, it forces me to register for **MFA** as below.

[image]

Comment: That helps, but I assume this means it would have to be configured each time a new org is added? Is there any way to follow the Orgs security policy?

Comment: Hi Neil P, yes, you can use a dynamic distribution group to automatically move external users to a group if certain conditions are met. Please see the updated answer.